Getting authorized mailboxes using Graph API
I can send mails using Authorization Code Flow for me@domain.com.
I can also send mails for other authorized mailboxes where I have 'send as' or 'send in the name of' rights setting the 'from'-property, e.g. group@domain.com.
But, is there a possibility to check with an existing accessToken what mailboxes this user has access to? I don't seem to find a way.
